# Error my first Phonegap App with Mobile Angular Ui

Tags: node.js, cordova, unicode, angular-ui, phonegap-build

I have a problem...I want to create my first Phonegap App with Mobile Angular Ui...I'm seeing the official doc on the Mobile Angular UI...So I run this command:

```
> C:\Users\blabla>npm install -g bower yo gulp
> generator-mobileangularui
```

I receive this error...

```
> npm WARN engine yo@1.4.6: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0","npm":">=2.1.0"}
> (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"}) |
> 
> 
> > buffertools@2.1.2 install C:\Users\blabla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m odules\generator-mobileangularui\node_modules\slug\node_modules\unicode\node_mod
> ules\bufferstream\node_modules\buffertools
> > node-gyp rebuild
> 
> /
> C:\Users\blabla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-mobileangul
> arui\node_modules\slug\node_modules\unicode\node_modules\bufferstream\node_modul
> es\buffertools>node "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\
> ..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild gyp ERR!
> configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable
> "python", you can set the PYT HON env variable. gyp ERR! stack     at
> failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
> e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:103:14) gyp ERR! stack     at
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
> -gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11 gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 gyp ERR! command
> "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
> les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
> C:\Users\blabla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generato
> r-mobileangularui\node_modules\slug\node_modules\unicode\node_modules\bufferstre
> am\node_modules\buffertools gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29 gyp ERR!
> node-gyp -v v0.13.1 gyp ERR! not ok npm WARN optional dep failed,
> continuing buffertools@2.1.2
> 
> 
> > unicode@0.6.1 postinstall C:\Users\blabla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m odules\generator-mobileangularui\node_modules\slug\node_modules\unicode
> > node install.js
> 
> try to read file /usr/share/unicode/UnicodeData.txt . Warning: using
> slow naiv Buffer.indexOf function! `npm install buffertools` to speed
> things up. /usr/share/unicode/UnicodeData.txt not found. try to read
> file /usr/share/unicode-data/UnicodeData.txt .
> /usr/share/unicode-data/UnicodeData.txt not found. try to read file
> UnicodeData.txt . UnicodeData.txt not found. try to download . GET
> unicode.org:80/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt
> C:\Users\blabla\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp -> C:\Users\blabla\
> AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
> C:\Users\blabla\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo -> C:\Users\blabla\Ap
> pData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js Error while downloading
> UnicodeData.txt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED Please download file
> manually, put it next to the install.js file and run `node install.js`
> again. /
> 
> 
> > yo@1.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\blabla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module s\yo
> > yodoctor
> 
> | Yeoman Doctor Running sanity checks on your system
> 
> V Global configuration file is valid V NODE_PATH matches the npm root
> V No .bowerrc file in home directory V No .yo-rc.json file in home
> directory
> 
> Everything looks all right! npm ERR! unicode@0.6.1 postinstall: `node
> install.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
> unicode@0.6.1 postinstall script. npm ERR! This is most likely a
> problem with the unicode package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm
> ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     node
> install.js npm ERR! You can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner
> ls unicode npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
> 
> npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! command "C:\\Program
> Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
> ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "bower" "yo"
> "gulp" "gen erator-mobileangularui" npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\blabla npm
> ERR! node -v v0.10.29 npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> C:\Users\blabla\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower -> C:\Users\blabla
> \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower npm ERR! npm ERR!
> Additional logging details can be found in: npm ERR!    
> C:\Users\blabla\npm-debug.log npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Can I fix this problem??? Thanks!

Comment: If you could copy-paste the error again and use **Code Sample** (Ctrl+K) instead of Blockquote for formatting, then it would be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

> npm WARN engine yo@1.4.6: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0","npm":">=2.1.0"} (current:n{"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})

That means you need to update your npm. You can update the NPM using the following command:

```
npm install npm -g
```

You can update Node as well, but it's not mandatory. To update Node to the latest version, which is `v0.12.2`:

```
npm install node -g
```

Comment: I think that this is not a problem...I use the after version because the last version of node.js doesn't work for me

Comment: You're talking about Node, right? Node's update is optional, but you will definitely need to update your npm.

Comment: C:\Users\bla>npm install --global latest-version
C:\Users\bla\AppData\Roaming\npm\latest-version -> C:\Users\bla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\latest-version\cli.js
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\bla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\bower\node_modules\bower-config requires graceful-fs@'~2.0.0' but will load

Comment: What command have you used to update? And did the update complete without errors? If all was done properly and you still face errors, re-installing npm & node would quickly fix the bugs.

Comment: Sorry but is npm in node??

Comment: *npm is a NodeJS package manager. As its name would imply, you can use it to install node programs. Also, if you use it in development, it makes it easier to specify and link dependencies*. So you need NPM to install Node and others.